# $f$ is Derivative in $x_0=0$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}\rightarrow f(\frac{1}{n})=a$ for ($a\in \mathbb{R}$), calculate $f'(0)$.

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be differentiable at $x_0=0$ and for all $\mathbb{N}\ni n\longmapsto f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=a$ for some $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then calculate $f'(0)$.

Hi there, I'm stuck in this question and I have a feeling I'm missing something, Perhaps using some theorem idk.
By typing "Derivative" I mean that the $\lim_{x\to0 }\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ is finite and exists.
I'm not sure how to use the idea of
"for all $n\in \mathbb{N}\rightarrow f(\frac{1}{n})=a$"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If limit exists then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {f(1/n)-f(0)}{1/n}=f'(0)$  but since f is continuous at $x=0$ thus $f(0)=\lim f(1/n)=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the derivative exists at zero, i.e., the limit
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$
exists, then it equals
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f\big(\frac1n\big)-f(0)}{\frac1n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a-f(0)}{\frac 1n}.$$
Now $f$ is continuous at $0$ (since it is differentiable there), so $f(0) = f(\lim\frac1n) = \lim f(\frac1n) = \lim a = a$, so the derivative is equal to
$$f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a-a}{\frac 1n}=0.$$

Comment: $f(x) = ae^{x}$ is such that $ae^{1/n} \to a$ and $f'(0) = a \neq 0$.

Comment: @Falcon, your function doesn't satisfy "$f(1/n)$ is constant for all $n\in \mathbb N$".

Comment: Ah ok my bad, the function has to be constant, I misread the question.

Comment: @Falcon are you the downvoter? I use the straightforward fact that if $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ exists, it must coincide with $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(\frac1n)$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I cannot change my vote unless the answer is edited. Edit and I will upvote.

Comment: @Falcon edited :)

Comment: Right I forgot that lim$\frac {1}{n}=a$ *facepalm*  Thank you!